# What are the core kubernetes Microservice components which Istio can replace?

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes, microservices, netflix, istio

We are planning to integrate a microservices platform which is running in Kubernetes and the architecture will be similar to the below reference architecture.

https://www.ibm.com/devops/method/content/architecture/microservices/1_0

What are the core components which can be replaces by Istio on the above Kubernetes microservices architecture?

I understand it can help in request routing, traffic management, policies and control.

If I need to migrate one of the similar project what are the components which is available in Istio which can be replaced in Kubernetes or vice versa?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question after having tried the integration yourself. For eg: try out a requesting routing example between the 2 platforms yourself and if it doesn't work or you want feedback on the approach, show us what you tried out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t replace any kubernetes core components. ISTIO is add-on for kubernetes to manage the micro service.
In the IBM article you can use ISTO for routing instated of Ingress Controller.

Comment: Thanks for your input.